# W3 Total Cache and wordpress mobile site redirect

Tags: php, wordpress, mobile

I used w3total cache for http://nirbhik.com . in my country bandwidth is precious and operamini is very popular. So developed http://m.nirbhik.com optimized for opera. Now I cant redirect nirbhik.com to m.nirbhik.com when its mobile device. I wrote a plugin that checks if its a mobile device then redirects to the mobile website.

The problem is it redirects for the first time. Second time the code is not run. I think because its cached the plugin does not even run. Then I required the plugin file from the wordpress index.php file, still the same result. Can someone please help?

edit: the plugin works as expected once w3total cache is deactivated and all cache is removed. So is there  a way to execute the plugin while w3 total cache is active?

Comment: for timing remobe / deactivate w3total cache plugin and check if all working for long time .. if yes then sure issues is with plugin or something else wrong

Comment: yes the plugin works when w3total cache is disabled and all cache is cleared. I am really stressed. Its almost 10 days and I am clueless..

Comment: ok one more thing , do you have any other plugin install on u r server ?.. if yes then ? what you can do is activate w3total plugin and then disable all plugin one by one .. and check .. if still you see the problem is caused by w3total plugin then u need to ask support from w3total master ..

Comment: well I studied and found that its not possible with w3totalcache. whatever plugin you use it only executes once the whole cache time. the only way around is sending users to the mobile site through .htaccess if they are from mobile..

Answer (score 0):

In "Manage User Agent Groups" try check "Theme Pass-through".